# .NET web service parameter is int[] before serialization, but ArrayOfInt after?

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a .NET web service which I would like to have accept either `List<int> foo` or `int[] foo`. I've tried declaring the paramater as each of those types, but it is converted to an ArrayOfInt after being ran through the serializer.

I have another web service which is implemented differently (old, moving to new structure) and, as such, it does not use System.Runtime.Serialization to generate its reference. This has the beneficial side-effect of not turning an int[] parameter into ArrayOfInt.

Interestingly enough, my web service's method happily returns int[]. It just will not accept int[] as parameter:

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Gets a list of Tasks from a list of Order IDs.")]
public List<TaskDto> GetTasksByIDList(int[] idList)
{
    return new List<TaskDto>();
}

[Test]
public void GetTasksByIDList()
{
    Task taskDto = WorkflowServices.CreateInstallTask(OrderID, TaskTemplateID, SiteID, DataCenterID,
                                                         DeviceTemplateID, DeviceName, Username);

    Task secondTaskDto = WorkflowServices.CreateInstallTask(OrderID, TaskTemplateID, SiteID, DataCenterID,
                                             DeviceTemplateID, DeviceName, Username);

    ArrayOfInt idList = new ArrayOfInt{ taskDto.ID, secondTaskDto.ID };

    List<Task> tasks = WorkflowServices.GetTasksByIDList(idList).ToList();

    if (tasks.Count() != idList.Count())
        throw new Exception(string.Format("Failed to find {0} tasks by ID. Received: {1}", idList.Count(), tasks.Count()));
}
```

Any ideas on how I can convince my service to accept int[] instead of ArrayOfInt? I do not want an end user to have to understand what/why an ArrayOfInt collection is necessary for only some scenarios and not others.

**UPDATE:**

Here's some more information regarding this issue. First, a screenshot of a web service I consider to be generated properly. Note that the WSDL declaration indicates ArrayOfInt, but it is still interpreted as int[]:

[image]
Now, by contrast:

[image]

And here's the top of each of their Reference.cs files. Note that the 'good' service reference is generated using ServiceModel, but the 'bad' service reference does not.

```
namespace CableSolve.Web.Api.Tests.ComponentServicesProxy {
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace="http://www.cormant.com/cswebapi", ConfigurationName="ComponentServicesProxy.ComponentServicesSoap")]
public interface ComponentServicesSoap {

namespace CableSolve.Web.Api.Tests.WorkflowServicesProxy {
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using System;
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="Order", Namespace="http://www.cormant.com/cswebapi")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
```

Comment: Which webservice was this? `Interestingly enough, my web service's method happily returns int[]. It just will not accept int[] as parameter:`

Comment: What do you mean by "converted to an ArrayOfInt after being ran through the serializer"? What happens when you add a service reference?

Comment: Can both services work with JSON instead of XML? That would be a hasty hack to fix the issues for now.

Comment: @jcolebrand - It is an ASMX web service written by myself.

Vitality - The service's contract indicates that it expects ArrayOfInt after adding as a service reference. If I interface directly with the class (without serialization needed) I am able to use int[] fine.

We've got 10+ services pre-existing and I'm trying to create a new one which looks similar, but leverages some new techniques as we introduce DTO objects in a better way. So, no, I would like to use XML serialization if at all possible.

Comment: If you use `WSDL.exe` to generate a client class in each direction that you need to consume, you won't have issues. It'll generate the XML correctly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to ensure that at least one complex type inside of my WebService derived from a class or was a class which is abstract. Failure to have a class which is abstract causes the serializer to opt for System.Runtime.Serialization as the serialization engine of choice, but by including an abstract class it is forced to use System.ServiceModel.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can pass an array directly like that and have the code recognize it. I've been able to pass a custom object containing an array without issues though

Comment: We currently pass arrays directly in for other services and the code recognizes it fine. The difference is that the old service reference was generated with     [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]. I believe it was possible to do this because I did not need to leverage any of the capabilities of System.Runtime.Serialization. However, now I do, but System.Runtime.Serialization wants to be 'more compatible' and is forcing int[] back to ArrayOfInt in order to be more language-independent.